# Magento 1.9.3 Overselling

Tags: cart, error, deadlock

I have a Magento website, that occasionally sell very requested and popular items with very limited quantity available. In that cases the traffic on the site become 20x/40x the normal traffic.

When we sell those items, many customer try to buy them, and in fact i sell more products that those available.

Supposing that i load a qty of 10, i sell 12-13 of them.

I noticed that if i use a configurable product the problem is even worst, using a simple product is a bit better, but still generate overselling.

The server is a managed private server, and the company said that even in that cases, the processor and the ram do not reach even 50%, so the problem is not on the server.

The product have just one thing that differ from my other products, the qty limit on the cart set to 1.

The only thing that I noticed on error logs is mysql deadlock on some queries.

Has anyone found a similar behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

We have also been experience the same issue on Magento 1.14 and recreating it once it has occurred is a bit of a problem too. But one time we were able to recreate it ,is when stock qty accidental went into negative(Negative State), people could be able to checkout the products though they were not in stock.
The negative state usual happens when re-indexing but not always ,still investigating the issue too.

Comment: Which Magento version are you using ?